# php-fpm "pool seems busy error". Why am I getting this?

Tags: php-5.3, php

I have a server with 64gb RAM using apache + fastcgi to connect to php-fpm.

I am running some load tests with ApacheBench. 500k reqs with 200 reqs/sec (goal is 10k/sec per server). I keep getting the "pool seems busy error" and am at a loss as to how to configure fpm properly to handle even 200reqs/sec. Feels like i'm missing something obvious.

fpm-config:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 8192
pm.start_servers = 2048
pm.min_spare_servers = 2048
pm.max_spare_servers = 2048
pm.max_requests = 8000
```

apache config:

```
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2048
ServerLimit     8175
MaxClients         8175
MinSpareThreads    2048
MaxSpareThreads     2048
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  8000
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My initial gut reaction is that having a max of 8000 children would seem to be quite a large number of processes to have running unless you have a lot of wait time per request.  After a while the large number of processes will actually cause a degradation of performance since  context switches would end up swapping the running processes in and out of CPU time, which takes time to do.  Unless you have a lot of external service calls with processes waiting a lot, this seems to be a little excessive.  Additionally, with an assumption of 20 MB allocated over the course of a request you are using 60+% of your free RAM just to serve start_servers.

As for the "pool seems busy" error, I don't know offhand.  It's tough (for me) to say without getting deeper into the environment.  What is your free CPU time like and your memory utilization when you are running AB?

I also wonder if there is a system limit on the number of connections an individual process (like the FPM) can have open...  Check ulimit -a